# Google Colab - Session Crashed error while training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a model on around 4500 text sentences. The embedding is however heavy. The session crashes for number of training clauses > 350. It works fine and displays results till 350 sentences though.

Error message:

```
Your session crashed after using all available RAM.
```

Runtime type - GPU

I have hereby attached the screenshot of logs.
I am considering training model by batches, but I am a newbie and finding it difficult to have my way around it. Any help will be appreciated. [session logs attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTDrT.png)

Comment: please add the necessary code

Answer (score 2):

This is basically because of out of memory on Google colab.
Google colab provides ~12GB Free RAM, to extend it 25 GB follow the instruction mentioned [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/upgrade-your-memory-on-google-colab-for-free-1b8b18e8791d).